# I need help deleting my 20GB error log

Tags: permissions, trash, rm

My storage was being filled for an unknown reason, until I found by error log is 20GB+. When I tried to delete from disk usage analyzer, it gave me an error “Failed to move file to trash|Unable to trash file /var/log/cups/error_log”. I tried deleting with terminal, and it gave me another error “rm: cannot remove ‘error_ log’: permission denied. The permission is “root”. Can anyone help me? If I restart, Ubuntu won’t be able to boot and will show me “Clean”.

Comment: I believe I'm using 22.04

Answer (score 0):

To delete the file, that is owned by root, then:
sudo rm /var/log/cups/error_log

This assumes you have sudo rights, the very first account created during Ubuntu's install has sudo rights.

Comment: It gives me an error that says “Sudo: error in /etc/sudo.conf, line 0 while loading plugin “sudoers_policy”” then it gives me “sudo: /usr/libexec/sudo/sudoers.so must be only be writable by owner” then “sudo: fatal error, unable to load plugins”

Comment: do you know the root password by any chance?

Comment: Mostlikely you are going to need to use a USB live image, boot up that image, then mount this drive, and delete the file.  I would also suggest to try and fix your sudoers file at the same time.

Comment: I don't think I know, what is a root password? Like the password you put on your user or something else?

Answer (score 0):

I used a Linux install usb and inputted the command: sudo rm /media/ubuntu/ccea0068-bc31-411c-a863-ad7c71834c72/var/log/cups/error_log